# How to avoid reloading every time page and tabs flutter

Tags: flutter

My problem is when I enter the app its open home page and it will load the data from api, i am navigate to other page and then again when i come home page its again load the data. Same problem in tabs. I have 3 tabs in a page and each and every time data will load, I want load data only once but when data update in database then I want to show changes that's why I am using stream builder for creating list.

**I am using stream builder.**

following are my code:

```
late Stream<AdminPostModel> stream = Stream.periodic(Duration(seconds: 3))
      .asyncMap((event) async => await getCurrentAdminPost());


  Future<AdminPostModel> getCurrentAdminPost() async {
    
    var url = "https:myURL.php?id=$getUserId&pageNo=$currentPage";
    var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
    var jsondata = jsonDecode(response.body.toString());
   

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
           return AdminPostModel.fromJson(jsondata);
      }
    else {
      return AdminPostModel.fromJson(jsondata);
    }
  }
```

**For making list of data:**

```
               Expanded(
                    child: StreamBuilder<AdminPostModel>(
                  stream: stream,
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.hasData) {
                      return ....Code
```

Comment: I'd suggest to use some state management solution instead of a direct streambuilder. That way you can request data in the background and update the UI only when you have some changes.

Comment: Do avoid reload of `StreamBuilder`, you can wrap whole `PageView` with `StreamBuilder` and pass the data to every page.

Comment: Actually i am new in flutter so, i am not getting your point. can you write answer please @sigmapie8

Comment: can you please briefly explain your point, how i can pass data and to wrap whole pge with stream builder? @AlexSunderSingh because i am new in flutter

Comment: Yeah, can you add a code for that page

Comment: means full page code? basically all UI part in stream builder which i was shown on code and also i was described method for calling api. Now which kind of data you want to add?@AlexSunderSingh

Answer (score 0):

That functionality called persist your class state & to achieve that you have to use wantKeepAlive

```
1) add  with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin after your State class

class ClassHome extends StatefulWidget{
@override
State<StatefulWidget> createState() => stateClassHome();

bool isPersistState;
ClassHome({required this.isPersistState});

}

class stateClassHome extends State<ClassHome> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
```

2. override wantKeepAlive variable

   ```
   @override
    // TODO: implement wantKeepAlive
    bool get wantKeepAlive => widget.isPersistState;

    @override
    void initState() {
    …
   ```
3. Write this condition in your build context

   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {

   ```
      if (wantKeepAlive) {
        super.build(context);
      }

      return Scaffold(
        ….
   ```
4. now in tabbar you’ve to set only isPersistState value if you set true then your data will not reload again & in some cases like when we’ve to deal with real time data then set it false

   ```
   ClassDashboard(isPersistState: true,)
   ```